# ".scrollBottom()" does not work

Tags: jquery

I have very little experience with jQuery, can someone one explain me what is wrong with the following code?

```
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.button').css({'display': 'none'});
       } else if ($(this).scrollBottom() > 200) {
        $('.button').css({'display': 'block'});
      }
    });
```

The first part of the code, where I want button to disappear - works, but not the second part of the function.

Comment: a jsfiddle will help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the local variable `scrollBottom` instead:

```
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.button').css({'display': 'none'});
       } else if (scrollBottom  > 200) {
        $('.button').css({'display': 'block'});
      }
    });
```

jQuery doesn't have scrollBottom() function.

Answer (score 2):

This will only create a variable, not define a function!

> var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

For simplicity, you can do this -

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

  if(scrollTop() > 400) {
    $('.button').css({'display': 'none'});
   } else if (scrollBottom > 200) {
    $('.button').css({'display': 'block'});
  }
});
```

Oh, and you can use *$('.button').show() / $('.button').hide()* instead of setting the .css().